# Xcode Compile Error - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Tags: xcode, serial-port, symbols

I recently added the file `Serial.c` and `Serial.h` to my Xcode project.

The code for `Serial.c` is as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

/*
* 'open_port()' - Open serial port on dock connector pins 13RX / 12TX
*
* Returns the file descriptor on success or -1 on error.
*/

int open_port(void)
{
int fd = -1; /* File descriptor for the port */

struct termios options; 

fd = open("/dev/tty.iap", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY); // O_NOCTTY - don't be controlling terminal, O_NODELAY don't care about DCD signal state
if ( fd == -1)
{
    // couldn't open the port

    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/tty.iap - ");
}
else
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

tcgetattr(fd, &options); // get current options for the port

// set the baud rate
cfsetispeed(&options, B2400);
cfsetospeed(&options, B2400);

// enable the receiver and set local mode
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

// set the new options for the port
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

return (fd);

}
```

The `serial.h` file,

`NSInteger openPort();`

I am trying to get the output of the Serial RX data stream from the iPhone into a NSLog statement.

I call the `OpenPort` function in the `ViewControllerSerialConsole.m` file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR    
NSInteger serial = openPort();
NSLog(@"The serial data is %d",serial);
//_serialView.text = serial;
#endif
}
```

The program compiles fine on the iPhone Simulator but doesn't compile on an iPhone.

I get the following error messages,

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_openPort", referenced from:
      -[ViewControllerSerialConsole viewDidLoad] in ViewControllerSerialConsole.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Any help on troubleshooting this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: In your code above you have a function called `open_port()`, but in the calling code, you call `openPort()` (notice the lack of an underscore). Is that intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app compiles fine for the simulator because you're not referring to the missing "`open_port`" or "`openPort`" symbol**.

In your Xcode project, select your "`Serial.m`" file in the list of files (along the left edge of the workspace) and look at the File Inspector for that file.

Make sure the checkbox is ***ON*** for your project in the "Target Membership" setting.

[image: Make sure Target Membership is selected for your .m file]

** while we are on the subject, is your function named correctly between your Serial.m & Serial.h file?  I see "`open_port`" in one and "`openPort`" in the other.

Comment: I changed `openPort` to `open_Port` and I am still getting the same error.  The "Serial" files are `Serial.c` and `Serial.h` which shouldn't make a difference.

Somehow I think I am getting this error because I am linking to a library in the `Serial.c` file that isn't included in the project, but I am probably wrong.

Ohh the checkbox was checked for the `Serial.c` file but not the `.h` file, which I don't think is possible to check for `.h` files.

Comment: You were right, it was an open_port typo that was preventing it from compiling, ty